# Is it possible to query Android Contacts using Room?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-room, android-contentresolver, android-architecture-components

I am building an Android app, which makes use of Contacts stored in Android Database.

The preferred approach is to use ContentResolver, and then query() as the app's data is exposed by the provider.

Fair enough..!!!

Can, I use Room here for querying the data which are exposed by providers?
Is it a fine approach? As I want to take advantage of abstraction and compile time check and internal mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly.

Room is only for your own internal database.

You *could* conceivably poll the contacts through its `ContentProvider` once per day (perhaps through a Job, so this work is done alongside other jobs). This data could then be inserted into your own Room database.

This could have negative reactions from users (why is this App storing my contacts?!). It would also not be updating instantly, only as often as you poll the data manually.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if I could go with internal mapping of data to pojos, without writing helpers of my own. I am not planning to store contact, just read and show some details. Okay, I will have to use contentresolver then. Thanks a lot..!!